# Warning message: in rbindlist(allargs) : NAs introduced by coercion: possible bug in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

While analysing some data, I came across the warning message, which I suspect to be a bug as it is a pretty straightforward command that I have worked with many times.

```
Warning message:
In rbindlist(allargs) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I was able to reproduce the error. Here's a code with which you should be able to reproduce the error.

```
# unique random names for column V1
set.seed(45)
n <- sapply(1:500, function(x) {
    paste(sample(c(letters[1:26]), 10), collapse="")
})
# generate some values for V2 and V3
dt <- data.table(V1 = sample(n, 30*500, replace = TRUE), 
                 V2 = sample(1:10, 30*500, replace = TRUE), 
                 V3 = sample(50:100, 30*500, replace = TRUE))
setkey(dt, "V1")

# No warning when providing column names (and right results)
dt[, list(s = sum(V2), m = mean(V3)),by=V1]

#              V1   s        m
#   1: acgmqyuwpe 238 74.97778
#   2: adcltygwsq 204 79.94118
#   3: adftozibnh 165 75.51515
#   4: aeuowtlskr 164 75.70968
#   5: ahfoqclkpg 192 73.20000
#  ---                        
# 496: zuqegoxkpi  93 77.95000
# 497: zwpserimgf 178 72.62963
# 498: zxkpdrlcsf 154 78.04167
# 499: zxvoaeflhq 121 75.34615
# 500: zyiwcsanlm 180 76.61290

# Warning message and results with NA
dt[, list(sum(V2), mean(V3)),by=V1]

#              V1  V1       V2
#   1: acgmqyuwpe 238 74.97778
#   2: adcltygwsq 204 79.94118
#   3: adftozibnh 165 75.51515
#   4: aeuowtlskr 164 75.70968
#   5: ahfoqclkpg 192 73.20000
#  ---                        
# 496: zuqegoxkpi  NA 77.95000
# 497: zwpserimgf  NA 72.62963
# 498: zxkpdrlcsf  NA 78.04167
# 499: zxvoaeflhq  NA 75.34615
# 500: zyiwcsanlm  NA 76.61290

Warning message:
In rbindlist(allargs) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

- 1) It seems that this happens if you don't provide the column names.
- 2) Even then, in particular, when `V1` (or the column you use in `by=`) has a lot of `unique` entries (500 here) and you don't specify column names, then this seems to happen. That is, this **DOES NOT** happen when the `by=` column `V1` has *fewer* unique entries. For example, try changing the code for `n` from `sapply(1:500, ...` to `sapply(1:50, ...` and you'll get no warning.

What's going on here? Its R version 2.15 on Macbook pro with OS X 10.8.2 (although I tested it on another macbook pro with 2.15.2). Here's the `sessionInfo()`.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.8.6 reshape2_1.2.2  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.8      stringr_0.6.2 tools_2.15.0
```

Just reproduced with `2.15.2`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.8.6
```

Comment: Same thing here with R 2.15.2 under Linux, data.table 1.8.6.

Comment: @juba, Thank you. Yes, I also confirmed it by updating my R version.

Comment: Is it not a problem with the `V1` column name ? If I rename V1 to V in `dt` then the problem seems gone. And I notice that there are two columns named `V1` in the resulting dataset that raises the warning ?

Comment: Yes, but that shouldn't be the reason for `NA`. Check with a smaller `data.table` and it will work.

Comment: @matthew, any idea about this error? I haven't checked if this has been filed a bug already (or possibly rectified in the current development version).

Comment: Does it happen in v1.8.7?  Btw, congratulations for asking the 500th question tagged `data.table`!

Comment: Oh thank you :)! I am not able to install `1.8.7` on my mac. It tried `install.packages("data.table", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")` and it gives me back: `package ‘data.table’ is not available (for R version 2.15.2)`. And when I try with `devtools` it ends up with `sh: make: command not found`.

Comment: That's odd. You have 2.15.2 and R-Forge builds with 2.15.2 so I'm baffled by that message. Unless R-Forge is in the process of building (I did commit last night), but it displays "Current" at rev 800, although the last commit was 801.  For devtools, does _any_ package work with devtools or is that the first time you tried devtools at all?

Comment: @MatthewDowle, I've used devtools and it has worked before, although I never tried on `data.table`.

Comment: R-Forge is likely building then (odd that it removes the package first). Anyway, I see the bug in 1.8.7 too. Answer on way ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE : Now fixed in v1.8.9 by Ricardo**

> o  rbind'ing data.tables containing duplicate, "" or NA column names
>   now works, #2726 & #2384. Thanks to Garrett See and Arun Srinivasan
>   for reporting. This also affected the printing of data.tables with
>   duplicate column names since the head and tail are rbind-ed together
>   internally.

---

Yes, bug. Seems to be in the print method of `data.table`s with duplicated names.

```
ans = dt[, list(sum(V2), mean(V3)),by=V1]
head(ans)
           V1  V1       V2     # notice the duplicated V1
1: acgmqyuwpe 140 78.07692
2: adcltygwsq 191 76.93333
3: adftozibnh 153 73.82143
4: aeuowtlskr 122 73.04348
5: ahfoqclkpg 143 75.83333
6: ahtczyuipw 135 73.54167
tail(ans)
           V1  V1       V2
1: zugrnehpmq 189 72.63889
2: zuqegoxkpi 150 76.03333
3: zwpserimgf 180 74.81818
4: zxkpdrlcsf 115 72.57895
5: zxvoaeflhq 157 76.53571
6: zyiwcsanlm 145 72.79167
print(ans)
Error in rbindlist(allargs) : 
    (converted from warning) NAs introduced by coercion
rbind(head(ans),tail(ans))
Error in rbindlist(allargs) : 
    (converted from warning) NAs introduced by coercion
```

As a work around, don't create data.table with column names `V1`, `V2` etc.

It's arising due to this known bug :

[#2384  rbind of tables containing duplicate column names doesn't bind correctly](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2384&group_id=240&atid=975)

and I've added a link there back to this question.

Thanks!

Comment: if you do the same on a small `data.table`: `dt <- data.table(V1=rep(letters[1:3], each=3), V2=sample(9), V3 = sample(9))`, the `print` doesn't produce errors... I am wondering why..?

Comment: @Arun Because only when `dt` is more than 100 rows (by default) does `print(dt)` print the top and bottom by `rbind`'ing together the `head` and `tail`.