# Why is rbindlist "better" than rbind?

Tags: r, data.table, rbind, rbindlist

I am going through documentation of `data.table` and also noticed from some of the conversations over here on SO that `rbindlist` is supposed to be better than `rbind`.

I would like to know why is `rbindlist` better than `rbind` and in which scenarios `rbindlist` really excels over `rbind`?

Is there any advantage in terms of memory utilization?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

`rbindlist` is an optimized version of `do.call(rbind, list(...))`, which is known for being slow when using `rbind.data.frame`

---

### Where does it really excel

Some questions that show where `rbindlist` shines are

[Fast vectorized merge of list of data.frames by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863341/how-to-merge-a-list-of-data-frames-by-row/12718498#12718498)

[Trouble converting long list of data.frames (~1 million) to single data.frame using do.call and ldply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728407/trouble-converting-long-list-of-data-frames-1-million-to-single-data-frame-us/9730292#9730292)

These have benchmarks that show how fast it can be.

---

### rbind.data.frame is slow, for a reason

`rbind.data.frame` does lots of checking, and will match by name. (i.e. rbind.data.frame will account for the fact that columns may be in different orders, and match up by name), `rbindlist` doesn't do this kind of checking, and will join by position

eg

```
do.call(rbind, list(data.frame(a = 1:2, b = 2:3), data.frame(b = 1:2, a = 2:3)))
##    a b
## 1  1 2
## 2  2 3
## 3  2 1
## 4  3 2

rbindlist(list(data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 2:6), data.frame(b = 1:5, a = 2:6)))
##     a b
##  1: 1 2
##  2: 2 3
##  3: 1 2
##  4: 2 3
```

---

### Some other limitations of rbindlist

It **used to** struggle to deal with `factors`, due to a bug that has since been fixed:

[rbindlist two data.tables where one has factor and other has character type for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933846/) ([Bug #2650](http://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2650&group_id=240&atid=975))

It has problems with duplicate column names

see 
[Warning message: in rbindlist(allargs) : NAs introduced by coercion: possible bug in data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584510/) ([Bug #2384](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2384&group_id=240&atid=975))

---

### rbind.data.frame rownames can be frustrating

`rbindlist` can handle `lists` `data.frames` and `data.tables`, and will return a data.table without rownames

you can get in a muddle of rownames using `do.call(rbind, list(...))`
see

[How to avoid renaming of rows when using rbind inside do.call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972998/how-to-avoid-renaming-of-rows-when-using-rbind-inside-do-call/14973062#14973062)

---

### Memory efficiency

In terms of memory `rbindlist` is implemented in `C`, so is memory efficient, it uses `setattr` to set attributes by reference

`rbind.data.frame` is implemented in `R`, it does lots of assigning, and uses `attr<-` (and `class<-` and `rownames<-` all of which will (internally) create copies of the created data.frame.

Comment: FYI `attr<-`, `class<-` and (I think) `rownames<-` all modify in place.

Comment: @hadley  Are you sure? Try `DF = data.frame(a=1:3); .Internal(inspect(DF)); tracemem(DF); attr(DF,"test") <- "hello"; .Internal(inspect(DF))`.

Comment: @MatthewDowle hmmm, `attr<-` does make a copy of data frames, but not of atomic vectors or lists. Confusing!

Comment: @hadley Indeed. See http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Confused-about-NAMED-tp4103326.html

Comment: `rbind.data.frame` has special "hijacking" logic - when its first argument is a `data.table`, it calls `.rbind.data.table` instead, which does a little checking & then calls `rbindlist` internally.  So if you already have `data.table` objects to bind, there's probably little performance difference between `rbind` and `rbindlist`.

Comment: Note that bug 2650 has been fixed. I've edited the answer to indicate this.

Comment: mnel, this post perhaps needs editing, now that `rbindlist` is capable of matching by names (`use.names=TRUE`) and also fill missing columns (`fill=TRUE`). I've updated [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23923024/559784), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23933711/559784) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23933873/559784) post. Do you mind editing this one or is it okay if I do it? Either way is fine by me.

Comment: `dplyr::rbind_list` is also pretty similar

Answer (score 53):

By `v1.9.2`, `rbindlist` had evolved quite a bit, implementing many features including:

> - Choosing the highest `SEXPTYPE` of columns while binding - implemented in `v1.9.2` closing [FR #2456](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/378) and [Bug #4981](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/93).
> - Handling `factor` columns properly - first implemented in `v1.8.10` closing [Bug #2650](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/139) and extended to binding *ordered* factors carefully in `v1.9.2` as well, closing [FR #4856](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/359) and [Bug #5019](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/84).

In addition, in `v1.9.2`, `rbind.data.table` also gained a `fill` argument, that allows to bind by filling missing columns, implemented in R.

Now in `v1.9.3`, there are even more improvements on these existing features:

> - `rbindlist` gains an argument `use.names`, which by default is `FALSE` for backwards compatibility.
> - `rbindlist` also gains an argument `fill`, which by default is also `FALSE` for backwards compatibility.
> - These features are all implemented in C, and written carefully to not compromise in speed while adding functionalities.
> - Since `rbindlist` can now match by names and fill missing columns, `rbind.data.table` just calls `rbindlist` now. The only difference is that `use.names=TRUE` by default for `rbind.data.table`, for backwards compatibility.

`rbind.data.frame` slows down quite a bit mostly due to copies (which @mnel points out as well) that could be avoided (by moving to C). I think that's not the only reason. The implementation for checking/matching column names in `rbind.data.frame` could also get slower when there are many columns per data.frame and there are many such data.frames to bind (as shown in the benchmark below).

However, that `rbindlist` lack(ed) certain features (like checking factor levels or matching names) bears very tiny (or no) weight towards it being faster than `rbind.data.frame`. It's because they were carefully implemented in C, optimised for speed and memory.

Here's a benchmark that highlights the efficient binding while matching by column names as well using `rbindlist`'s `use.names` feature from `v1.9.3`. The data set consists of 10000 data.frames each of size 10*500.

*NB: this benchmark has been updated to include a comparison to `dplyr`'s `bind_rows`*

```
library(data.table) # 1.11.5, 2018-06-02 00:09:06 UTC
library(dplyr) # 0.7.5.9000, 2018-06-12 01:41:40 UTC
set.seed(1L)
names = paste0("V", 1:500)
cols = 500L
foo <- function() {
    data = as.data.frame(setDT(lapply(1:cols, function(x) sample(10))))
    setnames(data, sample(names))
}
n = 10e3L
ll = vector("list", n)
for (i in 1:n) {
    .Call("Csetlistelt", ll, i, foo())
}

system.time(ans1 <- rbindlist(ll))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 1.226   0.070   1.296 

system.time(ans2 <- rbindlist(ll, use.names=TRUE))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 2.635   0.129   2.772 

system.time(ans3 <- do.call("rbind", ll))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 36.932   1.628  38.594 

system.time(ans4 <- bind_rows(ll))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 48.754   0.384  49.224 

identical(ans2, setDT(ans3)) 
# [1] TRUE
identical(ans2, setDT(ans4))
# [1] TRUE
```

Binding columns as such without checking for names took just 1.3 where as checking for column names and binding appropriately took just 1.5 seconds more. Compared to base solution, this is 14x faster, and 18x faster than `dplyr`'s version.

Answer (score 0):

Then this probably should be considered a bug?

```
# let us make a very simple list here
l <- list('a' = 1, 'b' = 2, 'c' = 3)
l
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 3

# check that it is a list
class(l)
#[1] "list"
typeof(l)
#[1] "list"
```

And `rbind` can handle it without any problems

```
do.call('rbind', l) 
#    [,1]
# a    1
# b    2
# c    3
```

But when using `rbindlist` one gets this?

```
rbindlist(l)
Error in rbindlist(l) : 
  Item 1 of input is not a data.frame, data.table or list
```

The error message is more than confusing since we checked above that the input is a `list`, didn't we?
Is the correct application of the function for this simplest of cases documented somewhere?
Any hints appreciated ... since I was expecting similar or same results as with `do.call('rbind', l)` I am a bit confused why the `data.table` function decides to transpose the result of the equivalent call on the same list when I work around that wrong class error eg by doing this?

```
rbindlist(list(l))
# will result in
   a b c
1: 1 2 3
```

Comment: I don't get why the error message should be confusing. If you check the elements of your `l` you clearly see that they are neither `data.table`, `data.frame` or `list`, e.g., by using `lapply(l, class)`