# rbindlist two data.tables where one has factor and other has character type for a column

Tags: r, data.table

I just discovered this warning in my script that was a bit strange.

```
# Warning message:
# In rbindlist(list(DT.1, DT.2)) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

---

**Observation 1:** Here's a reproducible example:

```
require(data.table)
DT.1 <- data.table(x = letters[1:5], y = 6:10)
DT.2 <- data.table(x = LETTERS[1:5], y = 11:15)

# works fine
rbindlist(list(DT.1, DT.2))
#     x  y
#  1: a  6
#  2: b  7
#  3: c  8
#  4: d  9
#  5: e 10
#  6: A 11
#  7: B 12
#  8: C 13
#  9: D 14
# 10: E 15
```

However, now if I convert column `x` to a `factor` (ordered or not) and do the same:

```
DT.1[, x := factor(x)]
rbindlist(list(DT.1, DT.2))
#      x  y
#  1:  a  6
#  2:  b  7
#  3:  c  8
#  4:  d  9
#  5:  e 10
#  6: NA 11
#  7: NA 12
#  8: NA 13
#  9: NA 14
# 10: NA 15
# Warning message:
# In rbindlist(list(DT.1, DT.2)) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

But `rbind` does this job nicely!

```
rbind(DT.1, DT.2) # where DT.1 has column x as factor
# do.call(rbind, list(DT.1, DT.2)) # also works fine
#     x  y
#  1: a  6
#  2: b  7
#  3: c  8
#  4: d  9
#  5: e 10
#  6: A 11
#  7: B 12
#  8: C 13
#  9: D 14
# 10: E 15
```

The same behaviour can be reproduced if column `x` is an `ordered factor` as well. Since the help page `?rbindlist` says: `Same as do.call("rbind",l), but much faster.`, I'm guessing this is not the desired behaviour?

---

Here's my session info:

```
# R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
# Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
# 
# locale:
# [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
# 
# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
# 
# other attached packages:
# [1] data.table_1.8.8
# 
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
# [1] tools_3.0.0
```

---

## Edit:

**Observation 2:** Following @AnandaMahto's another interesting observation, reversing the order:

```
# column x in DT.1 is still a factor
rbindlist(list(DT.2, DT.1))
#     x  y
#  1: A 11
#  2: B 12
#  3: C 13
#  4: D 14
#  5: E 15
#  6: 1  6
#  7: 2  7
#  8: 3  8
#  9: 4  9
# 10: 5 10
```

Here, the column from `DT.1` is silently coerced to `numeric`.
**Edit:** Just to clarify, this is the same behaviour as that of `rbind(DT2, DT1)` with DT1's column x being a factor. `rbind` seems to retain the class of the first argument. I'll leave this part here and mention that in this case, this is the desired behaviour since `rbindlist` is a faster implementation of `rbind`.

**Observation 3:** If now, both the columns are converted to factors:

```
# DT.1 column x is already a factor
DT.2[, x := factor(x)]
rbindlist(list(DT.1, DT.2))
#     x  y
#  1: a  6
#  2: b  7
#  3: c  8
#  4: d  9
#  5: e 10
#  6: a 11
#  7: b 12
#  8: c 13
#  9: d 14
# 10: e 15
```

Here, the column `x` from `DT.2` is lost (/ replaced with that of `DT.1`). If the order is reversed, the exact opposite happens (column x of `DT.1` gets replaced with that of `DT.2`).

In general, there seems to be a problem with handling `factor` columns in `rbindlist`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### **UPDATE - This bug ([#2650](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2650&group_id=240&atid=975)) was fixed on 17 May 2013 in v1.8.9**

---

I believe that `rbindlist` when applied to factors is combining the numerical values of the factors and using only the levels associated with the first list element.

As in this bug report: 
http://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2650&group_id=240&atid=975

---

```
# Temporary workaround: 

levs <- c(as.character(DT.1$x), as.character(DT.2$x))

DT.1[, x := factor(x, levels=levs)]
DT.2[, x := factor(x, levels=levs)]

rbindlist(list(DT.1, DT.2))
```

---

As another view of whats going on:

```
DT3 <- data.table(x=c("1st", "2nd"), y=1:2)
DT4 <- copy(DT3)

DT3[, x := factor(x, levels=x)]
DT4[, x := factor(x, levels=x, labels=rev(x))]

DT3
DT4

# Have a look at the difference:
rbindlist(list(DT3, DT4))$x
# [1] 1st 2nd 1st 2nd
# Levels: 1st 2nd

do.call(rbind, list(DT3, DT4))$x
# [1] 1st 2nd 2nd 1st
# Levels: 1st 2nd
```

---

#### Edit as per comments:

as for observation 1, what's happening is similar to:

```
x <- factor(LETTERS[1:5])

x[6:10] <- letters[1:5]
x

# Notice however, if you are assigning a value that is already present
x[11] <- "S"  # warning, since `S` is not one of the levels of x
x[12] <- "D"  # all good, since `D` *is* one of the levels of x
```

Comment: Ricardo, great! thanks for filing the bug. I think what you explain is right, but part of the story. As in, in case of "Observation 1", there's no numerical values being combined. I mean to say that they behave differently depending if both columns are factors and also on the order with which you bind them. Does that sound about right?

Comment: (+1) thanks for the temporary workaround. Given the number of operations one performs using "factor", I'd like to have the priority of this bug bumped... (I'll wait a while before accepting the answer).

Comment: @Arun, please see the edit above in response to the question about observation 1

Comment: Ricardo, I understand that, but the fact that `rbind` does it right (retaining the class of the first argument) makes me wonder about the part in the documentation where it says "same as rbind". The fix is definitely good enough. I just wanted to bring to notice the part in `?rbindlist` and the functionality. But since it's already filed as a bug, I'm glad to wait for a fix, and work with the temporary solution until.

Answer (score 2):

`rbindlist` is superfast because it doesn't do the checking of `rbindfill` or `do.call(rbind.data.frame,...)`

You can use a workaround like this to ensure that factors are coerced to characters.

```
DT.1 <- data.table(x = factor(letters[1:5]), y = 6:10)
DT.2 <- data.table(x = LETTERS[1:5], y = 11:15)


for(ii in seq_along(DDL)){
  ff <- Filter(function(x) is.factor(DDL[[ii]][[x]]), names(DDL[[ii]]))
  for(fn in ff){
    set(DDL[[ii]], j = fn, value = as.character(DDL[[ii]][[fn]]))
    }
  }
 rbindlist(DDL)
```

or (less memory efficiently)

```
rbindlist(rapply(DDL, classes = 'factor', f= as.character, how = 'replace'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The bug is not fixed in `R 4.0.2` and `data.table 1.13.0`. When I try to `rbindlist()` two DTs, one of which has factor columns, the other one empty, final result gets this column broken, and factor values mangled (\n occuring randomly; levels are broken, NAs are introduced).
The workaround is to not rbindlisting a DT with an empty one, but instead rbindlist it with other DTs which also has payload data. Although this requires some boilerplate code.