# data.table and table unexpected behavior

Tags: r, data.table

The data comes from another question I was playing around with:

```
dt <- data.table(user=c(rep(3, 5), rep(4, 5)),
                 country=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,6)),
                 event=1:10, key="user")
#    user country event
#1:     3       1     1
#2:     3       1     2
#3:     3       1     3
#4:     3       1     4
#5:     3       2     5
#6:     4       2     6
#7:     4       2     7
#8:     4       2     8
#9:     4       2     9
#10:    4       2    10
```

And here's the surprising behavior:

```
dt[user == 3, as.data.frame(table(country))]
#  country Freq
#1       1    4
#2       2    1

dt[user == 4, as.data.frame(table(country))]
#  country Freq
#1       2    5

dt[, as.data.frame(table(country)), by = user]
#   user country Freq
#1:    3       1    4
#2:    3       2    1
#3:    4       1    5
#             ^^^ - why is this 1 instead of 2?!
```

Thanks mnel and Victor K. The natural follow-up is - shouldn't it be 2, i.e. is this a bug? I expected

```
dt[, blah, by = user]
```

to return identical result to

```
rbind(dt[user == 3, blah], dt[user == 4, blah])
```

Is that expectation incorrect?

Comment: Is country in as.data.frame(table(country)) a factor? If so this it is because the levels aren't the same in both.

Comment: @mnel, while you are right in that it is due `as.data.frame` coercing to `factor`, the expected behavior would be for the value to represent the label.  I think this is probably the same thing going on as with `rbindlist`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933846/rbindlist-two-data-tables-where-one-has-factor-and-other-has-character-type-for/15935715#15935715

Comment: @eddi, see update to my answer.

Comment: @eddi -- I think the issues with the naive use of factors within `j` when using `by`, might be worth an entry FAQ -- it isn't a bug. it is documented behaivour (see FAQ 2.3, but it really needs more explanation0 -- it is also consistent with naive use of factors in many cases.

Comment: @mnel so you're saying that I should **not** expect `rbind` and `by` above to return the same result for any `blah` and should instead expect their equality to be `blah`-dependent?

Answer (score 7):

The idiomatic data.table approach is to use .N

```
 dt[ , .N, by = list(user, country)]
```

This will be far quicker and it will also retain country as the same class as in the original.

Answer (score 5):

As `mnel` noted in comments, `as.data.frame(table(...))` produces a data frame where the first variable is a factor. For `user == 4`, there is only one level in the factor, which is stored internally as 1.

What you want is factor **levels**, but what you get is how factors are stored internally (as integers, starting from 1). The following provides the expected result:

```
> dt[, lapply(as.data.frame(table(country)), as.character), by = user]
   user country Freq
1:    3       1    4
2:    3       2    1
3:    4       2    5
```

**Update**. Regarding your second question: no, I think `data.table` behaviour is correct. Same thing happens in plain R when you join two factors with different levels:

```
> a <- factor(3:5)
> b <- factor(6:8)
> a
[1] 3 4 5
Levels: 3 4 5
> b
[1] 6 7 8
Levels: 6 7 8
> c(a,b)
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Comment: As a note of interest `dt[, lapply(as.data.frame.table(country), as.character), by = user]` gives an error.

Comment: But this has probably nothing to do with `data.table`: e.g. `as.data.frame.table(dt$country)` produces the same error.

Comment: @VictorK. Ok, do you then think `rbind` does the wrong thing?