# do.call rbind of data.table depends on location of NA

Tags: r, data.table, rbind, do.call

Consider this

```
do.call(rbind, list(data.table(x=1, b='x'),data.table(x=1, b=NA)))
```

returns

```
   x  b
1: 1  x
2: 1 NA
```

but

```
do.call(rbind, list(data.table(x=1, b=NA),data.table(x=1, b='x')))
```

returns

```
   x  b
1: 1 NA
2: 1 NA
```

How can i force the first behavior, without reordering the contents of the list?

Data table is really really faster in mapreduce jobs (calling data.table ~10*3MM times across 55 nodes, the data table is many many times faster than data frame, so i want this to work ...)
Regards
saptarshi

Comment: I'm guessing this happens because `NA` is logical and `as.logical('x')=NA`, so when `rbind` decides that that column is logical (based on its first argument), it coerces subsequent items to match. `do.call(rbind, list(data.table(x=1, b=as(NA,'character')),data.table(x=1, b='x')))` works...

Comment: By the way, there is an "optimized `do.call(rbind,...)`" for data.tables called `rbindlist`. There are a few q's about it on this site, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673550/why-is-rbindlist-better-than-rbind/15673654#15673654

Comment: @Frank -- Very helpful comments. I've added a reference to `rbindlist` to my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As noted by Frank, the problem is that there are (somewhat invisibly) several different types of `NA`. The one produced when you type `NA` at the command line is of class `"logical"`, but there are also `NA_integer_`, `NA_real_`, `NA_character_`, and `NA_complex_`.

In your first example, the initial `data.table` sets the class of column `b` to "character", and the `NA` in the second `data.table` is then coerced to an `NA_character_`. In the second example, though, the `NA` in the first `data.table` sets column `b`'s class to "logical", and, when the same column in the second data.table is coerced to "logical", it's converted to a logical NA. (Try `as.logical("x")` to see why.)

That's all fairly complicated (to articulate, at least), but there is a reasonably simple solution. Just create a 1-row template `data.table`, and prepend it to each list of `data.table`'s you want to `rbind()`. It will establish the class of each column to be what you want, regardless of what `data.table`'s follow it in the list passed to `rbind()`, and can be trimmed off once everything else is bound together.

```
library(data.table)    

## The two lists of data.tables from the OP
A <- list(data.table(x=1, b='x'),data.table(x=1, b=NA))
B <- list(data.table(x=1, b=NA),data.table(x=1, b='x'))

## A 1-row template, used to set the column types (and then removed)
DT <- data.table(x=numeric(1), b=character(1))

## Test it out
do.call(rbind, c(list(DT), A))[-1,]
#    x  b
# 1: 1  x
# 2: 1 NA
do.call(rbind, c(list(DT), B))[-1,]
#    x  b
# 1: 1 NA
# 2: 1  x

## Finally, as _also_ noted by Frank, rbindlist will likely be more efficient
rbindlist(c(list(DT), B)[-1,]
```

Comment: Of course that would presumably slow the `rbind`ing down somewhat in all cases. On the other hand, it might not be too hard to add a second 'colClasses' argument to `rbindlist()`, allowing users to pass in either a character vector of class names or a list with elements of the desired classes.