# Fastest way to union all

Tags: r

I am searching for the fastest way to union all 100000 list into a dataframe. 
The union all is not a do.call(rbind) problem because i want to put in one column the output and add the minimum of each list in a group( to better understand the output see my code below).

I have tried two different stuff that works but are pretty slow, so i am searching for something using data.table or dplyr or anything that will make it better .

Example to reproduce what i want :

```
a <- c(1:3) 
b <-  c(12:20)
relations <- list(a,b)
```

output with two different solution that i tried.

1 - solution basically concatenate dataframes with rbind looping on the elements of the list :

```
full_group <- NULL
    for(i in 1:length(relations))
  {
    full_group = rbind( full_group,
                data.frame( id = relations[[i]] , 
                group = min( relations[[i]])) )       
                print(i)        
}
```

2 solution : concatenate vectors and then create a a dataframe out of the results:

```
full_group <- NULL
groups <- NULL
id <- NULL
    for(i in 1:length(relations))
  {

id <- c(id , relations[[i]] ) 
groups <- c( groups , rep( min(relations[[i]]) , length(relations[[i]]) ) )
                print(i)        
}

 full_group = data.frame( id = id , 
                groups = groups )
```

Comment: Instead of re-allocating "id" and "groups" you could, equivalently, use `unlist(relations)` and `rep(sapply(relations, min), lengths(relations))` respectively.

Comment: read about `data.table::rbindlist`, related SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673550/why-is-rbindlist-better-than-rbind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by your second solution output, you want what `stack` does to lists

```
stack(setNames(relations,sapply(relations,min)))
```

```
   values ind
1       1   1
2       2   1
3       3   1
4      12  12
5      13  12
6      14  12
7      15  12
8      16  12
9      17  12
10     18  12
11     19  12
12     20  12
```

The call the `setNames` here sets the names for the groups, here the minimum element of each list. The same code works with `melt` from `reshape2` in place of `stack`, which as @akrun points out may be faster.

Stack and melt, however, will store the group as a factor and character, respectively. If a numeric is desired (probably, here), use a slight modification of its underlying code

```
stack2 <- function(x,i) data.frame(values=unlist(x), ind=rep.int(i, lapply(x, length)))

stack2(relations,sapply(relations,min))
```

This is as @alexis_laz was suggesting in the comments.

Comment: gosh, both of your solutions are so fast. Thanks for the answer !