# R apply function - which one to use?

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I am confused which apply family to use here.
I have a data frame `mydf` as

```
terms
A
B
C
```

I want to apply custom function to each of the values and get results in new columns like below

```
terms Value1 Value2 ResultChar
A     23     45     Good
B     12     34     Average
C     9      23     Poor
```

custom function is something like `myfunc("A")` returns a vector like `(23, 45, Good)`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How did you get 'Value1' and 'Value2' in the expected when your input dataset have only a single column i.e. `terms`?

Comment: Its a complex function with many values pulled from other data sources...All I'm passing is the character A. You may take a simpler example with a simple formula

Comment: You can loop with `lapply` ie. `lapply(mydf$terms, function(x) ...)` without more info, it is difficult to suggest

Comment: @akrun So which question should this be a duplicate of?  http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39010839/timeline doesn't reveal the old dupe link any longer.  Anyway, this might be a good time to flag for mod attention.

Comment: @tripleee: [post history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39010839/revisions) does.

Comment: @tripleee This question is not very clear to begin with.  Secondly, it is more of a general question.  So, I thought the link in my solution post fits well.

Comment: This question is clearly not asking why `rbindlist()` is better than `rbind()`, which is what the linked duplicate was showing.  Therefore, I reopened it.

Comment: @DirtySockSniffer  I would say the question was not all clear.  If the OP wants to select which `apply` function to do, perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega) might be the one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want a data frame output, as you have different data type across columns. So you need define your `myfunc` to return a data frame.

Consider this toy example:

```
mydf <- data.frame(terms = letters[1:3], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
myfunc <- function (u) data.frame(terms = u, one = u, two = paste0(u,u))
```

---

Here is one possibility using basic R features:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(mydf$terms, myfunc))
#  terms one two
#1     a   a  aa
#2     b   b  bb
#3     c   c  cc
```

Or you can use `adply` from `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)
adply(mydf, 1, myfunc)
#  terms terms.1 two
#1     a       a  aa
#2     b       b  bb
#3     c       c  cc
```

(>_<) it is my first time trying something other than R base for a data frame; not sure why `adply` returns undesired column names here...

Comment: **Moderator note**: comments are not for extended discussion; take this to chat please.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `rbindlist` with `lapply`.  It would be more efficient

```
 library(data.table)
 rbindlist(lapply(mydf$terms, myfunc))
```

If needed, I can show the benchmarks.  But, they are already shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673550/why-is-rbindlist-better-than-rbind)