# How to make the long numbers not shown scientific mode in data.table in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I have several .csv files in a folder. I want to read them all once by using the command

```
library(data.table)
path <-path
list <-  list.files(path,pattern="*.csv")
files <- paste(path,list,sep='/')
DT <- do.call(rbind, lapply(files, fread))
```

However, since the first column is a 12 digits number, data.table shows it in a scientific number way, like

```
5.43971221673e-313
```

How should I convert all the scientific numbers into normal integers?

Thanks a lot!

First edit:
After I use the command

```
options("scipen"=100, "digits"=12)
```

It still shows the number like

```
5.43971221673e-313
```

Even after I applied the command

```
options(scipen=999)
```

It gives me back the number

```
0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000543971221673
```

And even 543971221673 is not the correct number, the correct one should be

```
110101001001
```

I was using data.frame to try to convert, it works.

```
a <- read.csv(files)
a[,1] <- as.character(a[,1])
```

But I would prefer to use data.table to make it fast.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Please use `rbindlist(lapply(files, fread))`.  `do.call(rbind...` is very slow.

Comment: @MattDowle why would the value change when you read this number `fread('110101001001\n')`

Comment: I got the answer here[Convenience features of fread](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Convenience-features-of-fread). by doing `options(datatable.integer64="character")`@Sathish

Comment: @YijiaoLiu Please post a demonstration of what you tried and the output as separate answer

Comment: @Sathish thanks a lot!

Comment: You said you _would prefer to use data.table to make it fast_. If all files have the same structure then you should consider to use `DT <- rbindlist(lapply(files, fread))` instead of `DT <- do.call(rbind, lapply(files, fread))`. By default, `rbindlist()` combines columns by position which is about 2 times faster than by column names. For details, please, refer to the excellent explanations and benchmarks in the answers to [Why is rbindlist “better” than rbind?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15673550/3817004).

Comment: @UweBlockglad to know, I have corrected it:)

Answer (score 2):

```
options(scipen = 999)
data.table(a = c(1e15, 2e15))
#                   a
# 1: 1000000000000000
# 2: 2000000000000000

options(scipen = 4)
data.table(a = c(1e15, 2e15))
#        a
# 1: 1e+15
# 2: 2e+15
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, but instead, it shows 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000543971221678;and 543971221678 is not the correct number, which should be 110101001002

Comment: that long string occurs ,  because you turned off scientific notation

Comment: to change it back to default, use `scipen = 0 `

Comment: The value is correct based on the data in your question, which is 5.43971221673e-313

Comment: @YijiaoLiu yes, you are right.

Comment: but if I imported the data with `read.csv` instead of data.table, after I apply `as.character()` to the column, the `110101001002` shows

Comment: I tried your suggestion, it is not working for me. I tried this command `a1 <- fread('110101001001\n'); as.character(a1$V1)`

Answer (score 2):

This issue is solved(at least temporarily) by the reference here[Convenience features of fread](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Convenience-features-of-fread#6-integer64-support).

'fread automatically detects large integers (> 2^31) and reads them as type integer64 from the bit64 package. '

Just need to

```
install.packages("bit64")
```

or put

```
options(datatable.integer64="character")
```

before the data.table, then it works. The example could be

```
library(data.table)
path <-path
list <-  list.files(path,pattern="*.csv")
files <- paste(path,list,sep='/')
options(datatable.integer64="character")
DT <- rbindlist(lapply(files, fread))
```

Thanks for @Sathish this is the first time I asked R question here!

Comment: Which version of data.table are you using?  I suspect it's less than v1.10.2 which contained news item: `When fread() or print() see integer64 columns are present, bit64's namespace is now automatically loaded for convenience.`

Comment: @MattDowlei am using 1.10.4 of data.table, R version is 3.3.2.

Comment: Ok. And did the warning message appear asking you to install `bit64` packages, and did you?  Setting `options(datatable.integer64="character")` is not recommended unless you really want numbers like that as character. Please remove that option, check you see the warning that `bit64` package is not installed and then install `bit64` and try again.

Comment: I've just discovered that the intended warning if you haven't got `bit64` installed is not happening due to a bug in that part of the code.  I've just fixed it [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/0351b48e18c5c804e1dda81fcb65f78e9ab2383f) . Sorry about that.

Comment: @MattDowleHi Matt these days I was busy doing the data cleaning work and I tried a little with package bit64 but not fully, thank you so much since I am working with my thesis now with this dataset.